# Stuck with recursive functions in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

This is my XML document:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text1-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2" /> 
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text2-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text3-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text4-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

         <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading3" /> 
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text2.1-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2" /> 
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text5-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text6-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading3" /> 
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text7-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text8-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>  

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1" /> 
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text9-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text10-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

<w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2" /> 
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text11-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text12-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>


    </w:body>
    </w:document>
```

One of the Stack Overflow members posting the xslt solution for this. But it won't work for the above mentioned XML document.

XSLT file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs w mf">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element()*">
  <xsl:param name="paragraphs" as="element()*"/>
  <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$paragraphs" group-starting-with="p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level)]">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level)]">
        <xsl:element name="Heading{$level}">
          <Title><xsl:value-of select="r/t"/></Title>
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group() except ., $level + 1)"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="document">
  <Document>
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(body/p, 1)"/>
  </Document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
  <Paragraph>
    <xsl:value-of select="r/t"/>
  </Paragraph>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My required output is:

```
<document>
   <paragraph>Text1-</paragraph>
   <Heading2>
      <Title>Text2-</Title>
      <paragraph>Text3-</paragraph>
      <paragraph>Text4-</paragraph>
     <Heading3>
      <Title>Text2.1-</Title>
      </Heading3>
    </Heading2>
      <Heading2>
         <Title>Text5-</Title>
         <paragraph>Text6-</paragraph>
         <Heading3>
            <Title>Text7-</Title>
            <paragraph>Text8-</paragraph>
         </Heading3>
      </Heading2>
   <Heading1>
      <Title>Text9-</Title>
      <paragraph>Text10-</paragraph>
      <Heading2>
      <Title>Text11-</Title>
      <paragraph>Text12-</paragraph>
   </Heading2>
   </Heading1>
</document>
```

Generated output is:

```
<Document>
   <Paragraph>Text1-</Paragraph>
   <Paragraph>Text2-</Paragraph>
   <Paragraph>Text3-</Paragraph>
   <Paragraph>Text4-</Paragraph>
   <Paragraph>Text2.1-</Paragraph>
   <Paragraph>Text5-</Paragraph>
   <Paragraph>Text6-</Paragraph>
   <Paragraph>Text7-</Paragraph>
   <Paragraph>Text8-</Paragraph>
   <Heading1>
      <Title>Text9-</Title>
      <Paragraph>Text10-</Paragraph>
      <Heading2>
         <Title>Text11-</Title>
         <Paragraph>Text12-</Paragraph>
      </Heading2>
   </Heading1>
</Document>
```

How can I solve this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an adaption of the code that should give the desired output for the sample you have posted in this question, it calls the function doing the grouping recursively as long as there are element with `w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val="HeadingX"`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs w mf">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element()*">
  <xsl:param name="paragraphs" as="element()*"/>
  <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$paragraphs" group-starting-with="p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level)]">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level)]">
        <xsl:element name="Heading{$level}">
          <Title><xsl:value-of select="r/t"/></Title>
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group() except ., $level + 1)"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="current-group()[self::p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level + 1)]]">
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $level + 1)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="document">
  <Document>
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(body/p, 1)"/>
  </Document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
  <Paragraph>
    <xsl:value-of select="r/t"/>
  </Paragraph>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative style-sheet, tested on Saxon. It is a little more verbose, but it is more efficient because, unlike Martin's solution, it limits the recursion to the minimum necessary.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:user="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239392"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs fn w user">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="user:level-of-p" as="xs:string">
 <xsl:param name="para" as="element()" />
 <xsl:sequence select="substring( $para/w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val, 8)" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template name="grouped-p">
 <xsl:param name="p-nodes" as="element()*" />

 <xsl:variable name="vals" as="xs:integer*">
  <xsl:for-each select="$p-nodes[user:level-of-p(.)]">
   <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="ascending" select="user:level-of-p(.)" />
   <xsl:sequence select="user:level-of-p(.) cast as xs:integer" />
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:variable name="level" as="xs:integer" select="($vals,-1)[1]" />
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$level = -1">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$p-nodes" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <xsl:variable name="grouping-val" select="concat('Heading',$level)" />
   <xsl:for-each-group select="$p-nodes" group-starting-with="w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val = $grouping-val]">
     <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="user:level-of-p(.)">
       <xsl:element name="{$grouping-val}">
        <Title><xsl:value-of select="w:r/w:t[1]" /></Title>
        <xsl:call-template name="grouped-p">
         <xsl:with-param name="p-nodes" select="current-group()[position() > 1]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="grouped-p">
         <xsl:with-param name="p-nodes" select="current-group()" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w:document">
  <document>
    <xsl:call-template name="grouped-p">
     <xsl:with-param name="p-nodes" select="w:body/w:p" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w:p">
  <paragraph>
    <xsl:value-of select="w:r/w:t"/>
  </paragraph>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```